# Bootstrap accordions and tabbed nav in one page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion, tabbed-interface

I have a site I'm building and I want to have tab nav with different accordion things on each tab. I've done this; but the one tab I've placed it in copies over to the other tabs.

I want it so that each tab has a different set of accordion links that load different things per tab.

Is this possible?

(edit): here's what I have so far:

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>beerwinefoodmixer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="assets/img/bws-logo.png" class="logo"/>
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<figure class="figtail"><img src="assets/img/cocktail.png" class="cocktail"/></figure>
<p class="rwmatch">There are many cocktail varieties, depending on the base spirit you can blend together many different flavours. Click through the tabs below to discover what you can create with some simple ingredients.</p>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Scotch Based</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Rum Based</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Vodka Based</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bourbon Based</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gin Based</a></li>
</ul>
<br><br>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-1">
        <p>Recipes for Scotch Go Here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-2">
        <div class="rumtab">
            <div role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion-1">
                <!--panel 1-->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-1 .item-1">Bacardi Cocktail:</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in item-1">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span>50ml Bacardi rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />10ml Grenadine<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--panel 1-->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-1 .item-2">Between the sheets:</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-2">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span>25ml White Rum<br />25ml Cognac<br />25ml Cointreau<br />5ml Gomme<br />Lemon twist<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-1 .item-3">Daiquiri:</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-3">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span>50ml Rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />15ml Sugar Syrup<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-2 .item-1">Dark n Stormy:</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in item-1">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span>50ml Black Rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />Top with Ginger beer<br />Lime wedge<br />Build in glass<br />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-2 .item-2">El Floridita no.1:</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-2">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span>50ml Rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />10ml gomme<br />10ml Maraschino liqueur<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-2 .item-3">El Presidente:</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-3">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span>50ml White Rum 25ml<br />Pineapple juice<br />20ml Lime juice<br />10ml Grenadine<br />Lime wedge<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-3">
        <p>Recipes for Vodka Go Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-4">
        <p>Recipes for Bourbon Go Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-5">
        <p>Recipes for Gin Go Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="redwine.html">Red Wine</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="whitewine.html">White Wine</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="beer.html">Craft Beer</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="whitemeat.html">White Meat</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="redmeat.html">Red Meat</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="dessert.html">Dessert</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

the css:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default{
  background-color:#ED7228;
  color:black;
  text-align: center;


}
nav.navbar.navbar-default-1{
  background-color:#ED7228;
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
}

div.navbar-header{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav a{
  color:#000
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav{
  background-color: #ed7228;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;

}



img.logo{
  display:flex;
  margin:auto;
  height:100px;
}

div.row{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ED7228;
  color:#fff;
}

h1.menu{
  background-color:#000;
}

div#center.col-md-4{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

div#bottom-row.row{
}

img.cocktail{
  height:150px;
}

div#bottom.row{
  background-color:white;
}

img.steak{
  height:150px;
}

img.chicken{
  height:150px;
}

img.dessert{
  height:150px;
}

img.redwine{
  height:150px;
}

img.whitewine{
  height:150px;
}

img.beer{
  height:150px;
}

figure.figred{

  margin-left: 150px;
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
}

figure.figwhite{

  margin: auto;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
}

figure.figbeer{

  margin-right: 150px;
  align:right;
  display:inline-block;
}

figure.figchick{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:auto;
}

figure.figsteak{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:auto;

}

figure.figdess{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
}

figure.figtail{
  display:inline-block;

  margin: auto;
}

h4.BWS{
  text-align:center;
}

div.navbar-header{
  text-align:center;
}

article.rwmatch{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;

  height:100px;
}

div.col-md-4{
  display:initial;
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
}

p{
  display:inline-block;
}

p.rwmatch{
  display: inline-block;
  width:400px;
  text-align:justify;
}

figure.figwhite_1{
  width:100px;
  margin-right:75px;
  margin-left:55px;
  display:inline-block;
}

p.wwmatch{
  width:400px;
  text-align:justify;
}

figure.beer{

  display:inline-block;
}

div.imagebox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p.sectionlink{
  margin: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.sectionlink-1{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.rumtab{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: We can't help you until you share your code.

Comment: please see edits above. it is the code for what I want to achieve and the css (the css is a bit messy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Your whole html with following, You didn't close `</div>` properly.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>beerwinefoodmixer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img src="assets/img/bws-logo.png" class="logo"/>
            <div class="navbar-header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <figure class="figtail"><img src="assets/img/cocktail.png" class="cocktail"/></figure>
    <p class="rwmatch">There are many cocktail varieties, depending on the base spirit you can blend together many different flavours. Click through the tabs below to discover what you can create with some simple ingredients.</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Scotch Based</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Rum Based</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Vodka Based</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bourbon Based</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gin Based</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br><br>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-1">
            <p>Recipes for Scotch Go Here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-2">
            <div class="rumtab">
                <div role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion-1">
                    <!--panel 1-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-1 .item-1">Bacardi Cocktail:</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in item-1">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>50ml Bacardi rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />10ml Grenadine<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--panel 2-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-1 .item-2">Between the sheets:</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-2">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>25ml White Rum<br />25ml Cognac<br />25ml Cointreau<br />5ml Gomme<br />Lemon twist<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--panel 3-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-1 .item-3">Daiquiri:</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-3">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>50ml Rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />15ml Sugar Syrup<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion-2">
                    <!--panel 1-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-2 .item-1">Dark n Stormy:</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in item-1">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>50ml Black Rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />Top with Ginger beer<br />Lime wedge<br />Build in glass<br />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--panel 2-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-2 .item-2">El Floridita no.1:</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-2">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>50ml Rum<br />25ml Lime juice<br />10ml gomme<br />10ml Maraschino liqueur<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--panel 3-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" aria-expanded="false" href="#accordion-2 .item-3">El Presidente:</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse item-3">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>50ml White Rum 25ml<br />Pineapple juice<br />20ml Lime juice<br />10ml Grenadine<br />Lime wedge<br />Shake hard and fine strain<br />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-3">
            <p>Recipes for Vodka Go Here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-4">
            <p>Recipes for Bourbon Go Here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-5">
            <p>Recipes for Gin Go Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br />
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="redwine.html">Red Wine</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="whitewine.html">White Wine</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="beer.html">Craft Beer</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="whitemeat.html">White Meat</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="redmeat.html">Red Meat</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="dessert.html">Dessert</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this hopefully either tonight or tomorrow morning. And mark as answer after i have tried it out. Cheers

Comment: Glad to help you mate. It's working. Accept as answer if it's working for you.